# I am trying to import a csv file into HDFS. I am getting a error that states: -cp: Not enough arguments expected 2 but got 1?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hdfs, hadoop2, amazon-emr, hue

I am using putty ssh to import my csv file to **HUE AWS HDFS**. 
So far I have made a directory using the command 
`hadoop fs -mdkir /data`

after the directory I am trying to import my csv file using command:
`hadoop fs -cp  s3://cis4567-fall19/Hadoop/SalesJan2  009.csv`

However I am getting a error that states :
`-cp: Not enough arguments: expected 2 but got 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your command the destination HDFS directory to where the file needs to be copied is missing.

The syntax is `hadoop fs -cp <source_HDFS_dir/file> <destination_HDFS_dir/>`

The correct command should be

`hadoop fs -cp s3://cis4567-fall19/Hadoop/SalesJan2 009.csv /tmp`

Please note that I've mentioned the destination as `/tmp` just as an example. You can replace it with the required destination directory name.